# How to use a custom id column in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain object that has a property that i want to be used as the id by GORM, the reason being is that ill be saving lists of this object and i want existing rows to be **updated** if the id already exists in the database

Lets assume that my property i want as the PK is called  **listId**

Ive seen several approaches to this, which is best?

1:

```
id generator: 'identity', column: 'listId'
```

2:

```
  static mapping = {
    id generator:'assigned'
  }
  def getKey = {
    return listId;
  }
```

or something entirely different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  static mapping = {
    id generator: 'assigned', name: "listId", type: 'string'
  }
```